# Certain totient chain growth assuming Carmichael's Totient Function Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

Assume the [Carmichael's Totient Function Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture).

Consider the totient chain

$$n_0=\phi(3^2)\rightarrow n_1=\phi((\phi^{-1}(n_0))^2)\rightarrow n_2=\phi((\phi^{-1}(n_1))^2)\rightarrow\dots$$

where $\phi^{-1}(\phi(x))$ is the smallest second integer $y\neq x$ such that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$.

**(1)** Does this chain grow doubly exponentially? (**Shown below by Greg Martin**)

**(2)** At every $i$ is there a prime $p_{i+1}$ with $p_{i+1}|n_{i+1}$ and $gcd(p_{i+1},\prod_{j=1}^in_j)=1$? What is the size of this prime?

What if $3^2$ is replaced by $a^k$ where $a,k+1\geq3$ and exponent in $\phi$ is $k$?

Answer (score 2):

The suggested dynamic is more clearly written (using $\phi(m^2)=m\phi(m)$) as $$n_{j+1}= n_j\phi^{-1}(n_j) \gt (n_j)^2,$$

which clearly shows superexponential growth in $j$.  Using $k$ in place of $2$ gets an inequality like $n_{j+1} \gt n_j^k$. Since it is unclear how $\phi^{-1}$ acts as a map, it should be tantamount to the Carmichael conjecture to
ask for a primitive prime factor for each $n_j$.

Gerhard "Remember Jacobi Says 'Always Invert!'" Paseman, 2016.06.07.

Comment: Further, it is unclear that the sequence $n_j$ has infinitely many terms, so the growth may stop.  Gerhard "But Let Us Be Hopeful" Paseman, 2016.06.07.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (1) is yes. Using the increasing lower bound
$$
\phi(n) > \frac n{4\log\log n} \quad\text{for }n\ge7
$$
(which follows from [known bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate)), we get
$$
n_{j+1} = \phi(\phi^{-1}(n_j)^2) > \frac{\phi^{-1}(n_j)^2}{4\log\log \phi^{-1}(n_j)^2} > \frac{n_j^2}{4\log\log n_j^2},
$$
which certainly implies $n_j \gg \exp((2-\varepsilon)^j)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I think $2$ is also true.

Comment: If $k\neq2$ should be $2^{2^{i\log k}}$?

Comment: You should note for clarity that the $n$'s you are using are different from those in the post.  Gerhard "I Would Use M's Instead" Paseman, 2016.06.07.

Comment: clarity shmarity, I just messed up! fixed now

Comment: Uh, I don't think so Greg.  You have an extra exponent.  However, phi(m^2)=m*phi(m), so you can still show super exponential growth independent of Carmichael's conjecture.  Gerhard "Since We Are Being Frank" Paseman, 2016.06.07.

Comment: Yes, extra squares, my fault. But I don't need $\phi(m^2)=m\phi(m)$; I'm literally plugging in $n=\phi^{-1}(n_j)^2$ in the lower bound.

Comment: OK, as long as you have $m/4\log\log m$ monotonic increasing where you use the inequality.  Gerhard "Not Valid For Small Naturals" Paseman, 2016.06.07.